# How can I create Neumorphism style in React Native using Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to make my React Native app in the style of neumorphism. I am using expo. Firstly what I tried doing, was to achieve that style without any 3rd party libraries, but since Android supports only elevetion property pretty much, I gave up on that idea. I've found several neumorphism packages for react native, but none of these seem to work for me.

- **react-native-neomorph-shadows** - doesn't support expo
- **neumorphism-ui** - doesn't support Android
- **react-native-neu-element** - had some problems with react-native-linear-gradient
- **rn-neumorphism** - honestly can't remember what was wrong

I'm trying to use **react-native-neumorphic**, since it should support expo. But I am running into this error:

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "BVLinearGradient" was not found in the UIManager.
```

What fixed the error for me, was to install expo-linear-gradient instead of react-native-linear-gradient. After that, there is no errors, the component renders, but it has no shadow (it's like I'd render just the child component of that Neumorphic component).

Any tips?